# Inspect a Ramdrive?

Tags: linux, centos, fstab, ramdisk

I have mounted a ramdrive via `/etc/fstab`.

And I would like to inspect the properties of the drive such as the memory policy (e.g. bind, prefer, or?) to make sure all properties are expected.

How can I do so?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Executing `mount` without any arguments gives a list of mounted filesystems, including tmpfs, and their properties:

```
tmpfs on /mountpoint type tmpfs (rw,relatime)
```